# WebApplication automatically deployed as EAR

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, weblogic

I have checked out a web application from SVN and added it as a Maven project. Now when I'm trying to deploy it to a Weblogic Server 12c, its getting deployed as EAR and not WAR. How can I deploy it as WAR while running from eclipse.

**Update**

I'm able to run it properly by exporting as WAR. But from eclipse it exports as EAR and it does not run. From eclipse i need to deploy as WAR. May be that can solve my issue.

Comment: How are you deploying it? With eclipse's deploy-tool?

Comment: @Kayaman yes... directly `run it on server`

Comment: why do you care about it being a war, not an ear?

Comment: its not running is my issues. showing as web apps unavailable under the context url. i need it to run as normal war

Comment: Then you have a different issue, deploying it as a war is not going to make that issue go away. You need to find the root of the issue in stead of trying to run away from having to understand it.

Comment: @Gimby thanks gimby. I shall give it a try then... i though issue was arising because its not coming as war. but this EAR is not deploying properly even. and how come its deploying as EAR when my maven says WAR

Comment: If you open up the ear file `jar xvf your.ear` it might contain a war inside of it. An ear file is used to contain multiple war files.